# Text-decoration underline not working after position absolute

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

http://jsfiddle.net/ZPNxh/2/

When I position the overlayer absolutely, the hover (underline) on the h3 doesn't work (although the A tag wraps everything).

When it's normally positionned, the underline works like a charm.

I tried playing with the z-indexes, in vain

Any ideas ?

Comment: what do you mean with "doesn't work" because to me it get underlined on mouse over. Isn't that right?

Answer (score 2):

First off, `a` tag is an inline element and `h3` tag is a block element! You cannot place the `h3` tag inside the `a` tag. So, first remove the `a` tag and make it as some other block level element like a `div`.

The `:hover` pseudo class doesn't work on IE 6 other than for `a` tag. So, if you are using the `div` tag and targetting it as `div:hover`, that works in all browsers, except those less than IE 7.

Still, if you wanna use the same markup, please add this:

```
a {display: block;}
```

So that, it renders it as a block element, rather than inline element, holding the `h3` and `div`!

### Preview

[image]

And one another best way is to add `border-bottom: 2px solid;` instead of `text-decoration`!